# Lock volume on Mixer in Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, audio, volume-mixer

I have an application that keeps turning its volume inside the Windows mixer to 1, is there a way to either lock the volume at a certain level, or disable the mixing completely? Its driving me insane.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at either [VolumeLock](http://www.actualsolution.com/volume-lock/) or [PowerMixer](http://www.actualsolution.com/power-mixer/). I use VolumeLock on my HTPC and it works great.